# Flutter and Android/Ios design

Tags: flutter

I have a question about flutter design. Normally cuppertino design is for IOS and material design for Android.
But when you create a flutter you have to choose one.
How we can have easily same code but different design ?
Do a if Platform is IOS and after redirect to cuppertino design ?
Because I don't think material design is a good practice for Ios isn't it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets. It does just what you want, it renders components according to your system on mobile (ios or android)